# An unknown exception is coming before opening the form

Tags: c#, .net

An exception is coming in the following code. Can you please tell me whats the wrong in this code? It take time to open the form. An message box in catch block is show before open the form. My database is running but I don`t know why its not running smoothly? 
Please guide...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IMS
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // To set up a connection object
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(); 
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'iMSDataSet1.Part_Group'
        //table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.part_GroupTableAdapter.Fill(this.iMSDataSet1.Part_Group);


        con.ConnectionString = "Data     Source=.\\DataDirectory\\IMS.sdf;Password=ims;Persist Security Info=True";
        //open up a connection to the database
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database Exception");
        }
        //Close up a connection to the database
        con.Close();

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void AddPartGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cb;
        cb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

        //DataRow dRow = 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, you need to change how you handle exceptions. This:

```
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Database Exception");
}
```

is not terribly useful. Not only is it catching *all* exceptions (instead of just specific ones); it's ignoring the exception itself. At the very least, use something like:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Database Exception: " + e.Message);
    // Now log e.ToString() somewhere as well
}
```

That will help you work out what's going wrong. As an aside, I would try *not* to do database operations in the UI thread, and you should *usually* only catch specific exceptions - but your most immediate change should be to stop ignoring the useful information in the exception which is being thrown.

Note that also, after you've caught the exception you're then continuing as if nothing's wrong - when in fact this sounds like it may well be a fatal error, and the rest of your application is going to fail pretty soon afterwards. You should probably force your application to close at this point (with an appropriate explanation), rather than trying to continue in a broken state. (Other options include retrying the failing operation etc - the important thing is not to just continue as if everything was okay.)

Comment: Thanks Jon for replying. Exception throwing following error

_"Database Exception A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26- ERROR Locating Server/ Instance Specified)"_
I am reading from this tutorial http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p3.html . Kindly explain what that mean? What I should to do?

Comment: @m3nhaq: Well, the exception tells you exactly what you should try to do - verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. Does SQL Studio allow you to browse using the connection string you've specified? Basically you won't be able to do anything else until you've worked out how to connect to the database, and that's not going to have anything to do with your actual *code* here.